# Printing all fields of a database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

### My aim

I'm trying to display, for every table in my database, an HTML one which should have:

- The first line containing names of the columns
- The other lines (one per record) containing the fields

Just like this one:
[image: How every table should be]

### My code

```
<?php
$num = 0;
$connessione = mysqli_connect();
$tables = mysqli_query($connessione,"SHOW TABLES");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($tables)){
        echo '<i>'.$row['Tables_in_my_db'].'</i><table border="1px"><tr>';
        $columns = mysqli_query($connessione,"SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$row['Tables_in_my_db']);
            while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($columns)){
            echo '<td><b>'.$row2['Field'].'</b></td> ';
                }
            echo '</tr>';
$query = "SELECT * FROM ".$row['Tables_in_my_db'];
             $fields = mysqli_query($connessione,$query);
            echo '<tr>';
                while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($fields)){
                echo '<td>'.$row3[$num].'</td>';
                $temp = $num+1;
                if($row3[$temp]==""){break;}
                $num = $temp;
            }
       echo '</tr></table>';
       $num = 0;
   }
?>
```

### What's not working

I get only the first two lines per table as output (the first containing the names of the columns, the second one with some values which aren't in the same record of database).

### Debugging

`error_reporting(E_ALL)` returns a bunch of `Notice: Undefined offset on line 19`

### My question

How can I fix this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$connessione = mysqli_connect();
$tables = mysqli_query( $connessione, "SHOW TABLES" );
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $tables ) ){
    echo '<i>' . $row[ 'Tables_in_my_db' ] . '</i><table border="1px">';
    // Show columns
    $columns = mysqli_query( $connessione, "SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$row[ 'Tables_in_my_db' ] );

    // Here we collect column names to output row values in the same order
    $columnNames = array();
    echo '<tr>';
    while( $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array( $columns ) ){
        $columnNames []= $row2[ 'Field' ];
        echo '<td><b>' . $row2[ 'Field' ] . '</b></td> ';
    }
    echo '</tr>';

    // Show table rows
    $query = "SELECT * FROM " . $row[ 'Tables_in_my_db' ];
    $fields = mysqli_query( $connessione, $query );

    $maxRows = 10;
    while( $row3 = mysqli_fetch_array( $fields ) ){
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach( $columnNames as $columnName ) {
            echo '<td>' . $row3[ $columnName ] . '</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
        $maxRows--;
        if( !$maxRows ) {
            break;
        }
    }

    echo '</table>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure if this is the problem, but you might want to change this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM ".$row['Tables_in_my_db'];
         $fields = mysqli_query($connessione,$query);
        echo '<tr>';
            while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($fields)){
            echo '<td>'.$row3[$num].'</td>';
            $temp = $num+1;
            if($row3[$temp]==""){break;}
            $num = $temp;
        }
   echo '</tr></table>';
```

Into this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM ".$row['Tables_in_my_db'];
         $fields = mysqli_query($connessione,$query);
        $output = '<tr>';
            while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($fields)){
            $output .= '<td>'.$row3[$num].'</td>';
            $temp = $num+1;
            if($row3[$temp]==""){break;}
            $num = $temp;
        }
   $output .= '</tr></table>';
   echo $output;
```

Same goes for the first part of the code

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) With the code you suggested, I get Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given on line 16 for every table generated, which has just the first line (the one with names of columns)